# MS SQL Server ( How to fetch record based on count(*) and date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have requirement in MS SQL Server, fetch group of keywords order by count , and if count value same latest count should be on top,

Table - fields

```
id, keyword, datetime
```

Query

```
SELECT 
       keywords,count( * ) as count 
FROM 
       xyztable 
GROUP BY 
       keywords 
ORDER BY
       count( * )
```

Here if count same of keyword and it should order by datetime

Thanks,
MK.

Comment: What's your problem / error message?

Answer (score 1):

Change your ORDER BY to:

```
ORDER BY count(*) DESC,datetime DESC
```

You can have multiple columns in order by and they have a ranking by the order you put them. In this case you order first by `count(*)` then, the ones with the same `count(*)` are ordered by `datetime`.

EDIT:

Re reading your question, i see that i was not entirely accurate. Yes you can order by multiple columns, but in your case you have an aggregate function (`COUNT(*)`) in there, so this is going to give you an error unless you put `datetime` in the `group by` also.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply ,I did the same in the Query for count( * ) desc,datetime desc , but it not taking based on the date , Actual result
keyword  count  datetime
Google   20     01/09/2013 10:10
Gplus     2     01/09/2013 10:12
yahoo     2     01/09/2013 10:13

in this both Gplus and yahoo count are same , and based time it should display

Expected result

Google   20     01/09/2013 10:10
yahoo     2     01/09/2013 10:13
Gplus     2     01/09/2013 10:12

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT keywords, count( * ) counts 
FROM t 
GROUP BY keywords 
ORDER BY count( * ), max(date) desc
```

Sample data:

```
create table t(keywords varchar(50), date date)

insert into t values
('x','20130901'),('x','20130904'),
('y','20130901'),('y','20130902'),('y','20130903'),
('z','20130903'),('z','20130906')
```

Results (**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7dfb6/17)**):

```
| KEYWORDS | COUNTS |    MAXDATE |
-----------|--------|------------|--
|        z |      2 | 2013-09-06 |
|        x |      2 | 2013-09-04 |
|        y |      3 | 2013-09-03 |
```

Comment: I tried the same , when I doing with pagination each page it get order by max(date) .

Comment: This query achieves your requirement `If the counts are same latest value should be on top`. You need to `Order by max(date) DESC` after ordering by count(*).

Comment: My Reuirement like this Actual result
keyword  count  datetime
Google   20     01/09/2013 10:10
Gplus     2     01/09/2013 10:12
yahoo     2     01/09/2013 10:13

in this both Gplus and yahoo count are same , and based time it should display

Expected result

Google   20     01/09/2013 10:10
yahoo     2     01/09/2013 10:13
Gplus     2     01/09/2013 10:12

Comment: That is exactly what above query doing `ORDER BY count( * ), max(date) desc`.